# No increase in speed when multithreading python hdf5 parsing function

Tags: python, multithreading, hdf5, h5py

I have a function that:

1) reads in a hdf5 dataset as integer ascii code

2) converts ascii integers to characters...chr() function

3) joins the characters into a single string function

Upon profiling, I found that the vast majority of the calculation is spent on the step #2, the conversion of the ascii integers to characters. I have somewhat optimized this call by using:

```
''.join([chr(x) for x in file[dataSetName].value])
```

As my parsing function seems to be cpu bound (the conversion of integer to characters) and not i/o bound, I expected to obtain a more/less linear speed enhancement with the number of cores devoted to parsing. To parse one file serially takes ~15 seconds...to parse 10 files (on my 12 core machine) takes ~150 seconds while using 10 threads. That is, there seems to be no enhancement at all.

I have used the following code to launch my threads:

```
    threads=[]
    timer=[]
    threadNumber=10
    for i,d in enumerate(sortedDirSet):
        timer.append(time.time())
     #   self.loadFile(d,i)
        threads.append(Thread(target=self.loadFileargs=(d,i)))
        threads[-1].start()
        if(i%threadNumber==0):
            for i2,t in enumerate(threads):
                t.join()
                print(time.time()-timer[i2])
            timer=[]
            threads=[]

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're probably running into the GIL.  http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python cannot use multiple cores (due to GIL) unless you spawn subprocesses (with `multiprocessing` for example). Thus you won't get **any** performance boost with spawning threads for CPU bound tasks.

---

Here's an example of a script using `multiprocessing` and `queue`:

```
from Queue import Empty # <-- only needed to catch Exception
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, cpu_count

def loadFile(d, i, queue):
    # some other stuff
    queue.put(result)

if name == "main":
    queue = Queue()
    no = cpu_count()
    processes = []

    for i,d in enumerate(sortedDirSet):
        p = Process(target=self.loadFile, args=(d, i, queue))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

        if i % no == 0:
            for p in processes:
                p.join()
            processes = []

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    results = []
    while True:
        try:
            # False means "don't wait when Empty, throw an exception instead"
            data = queue.get(False)
            results.append(data)
        except Empty:
            break

    # You have all the data, do something with it
```

The other (more complicated) way would be to use `pipe` instead of `queue`.

It would be also more efficient to spawn processes, then create a job queue and send them (via `pipe`) to subprocesses (so you won't have to create a process each time). But this would be even more complicated, so let's leave it like that.

Comment: Blast. GIL guts 95% of the usefulness of multithreading. I at first attempted to utilize multiprocessing.imap, but I found it difficult to work around the freeze_support errors. As well, I couldn't find the right way to utilize __name__ == '__main__' within my class method. Any hints?

Comment: @PaulD Well, Python is not designed for CPU bound tasks in the first place. But threads work well with I/O bound tasks. And I've updated the answer (that's how I would do that, but obviously depends on your context).

Comment: Thank you for your example. The problem I have is 1) my process spawning point isn't in main...it is in a class method. As well, the spawned method utilizes class member variables. I'm thinking I can't use multi-processing in this case?

Comment: @PaulD You can, it's just it gets more complicated. You can always create a pool of processes when you run your script (in main) and then just send your data to it. But this requires using pipes and you will need a listener thread in each subprocess and you will have to take care of killing that pool once the main process quits. As you can see it gets nasty. So maybe it would be easier to implement this piece of code in some other language and use [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)? Or possibly a C addon?

Comment: Complicated indeed...I regularly program in c++. My choice of using/learning python for this project was due to its supposed rapid prototyping. Sigh. The lack of adequate multithreading almost compels me to switch back to matlab and their handy parfor loops.

Comment: @PaulD Well, there is no such thing as perfect language. :) Coding in Python is indeed very fast, unless you are dealing with this kind of tasks. You have to pick a correct tool for the job. And it looks like Python is not what you are looking for, sorry.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29202/discussion-between-pauld-and-freakish)

Answer (score 0):

Freakish is correct with his answer, it will be the GIL thwarting your efforts.

If you were to use python 3, you could do this very nicely using [concurrent.futures](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/concurrent.futures.html). I believe PyPy has also backported this feature.

Also, you could eek a little bit more speed out of your code by replacing your list comprehension:

```
''.join([chr(x) for x in file[dataSetName].value])
```

With a map:

```
''.join(map(chr, file[dataSetName].value))
```

My tests (on a massive random list) using above code showed 15.73s using list comprehension and 12.44s using `map`.